# Connection to homestead Refused

Tags: laravel, ssh, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

Hey I have been trying to get my homestead running but I keep getting to the error:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 => 8000 (adapter 1)
    default: 443 => 44300 (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 => 33060 (adapter 1)
    default: 5432 => 54320 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection refused. Retrying...
```

I am running windows 10 and Virtual box 5.0.4

Comment: can you run vagrant up --debug and just give the output on the looping with detail error (if any)

Comment: hey Fredric Henri, I couldn't find any looping errors

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening right after the line 'default: SSH auth method: private key' and presents a connection refused error, so I assume it can be related to your ssh keys. Did you check if your ssh keys are set properly?

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "you@homestead"
```

Try running this again and set your public and private key paths in the homestead.yaml file (make sure it points to the file properly) then try again.

If the problem persists show us your homestead.yaml file so we can try to help better :) I hope I could be of help

Comment: hey cbcaio yes my ssh was set up right, at the time i posted this windows 10 could not be configured to run homestead but a new vb was released that supported it and after i got that everything works fine.
i appreciate the help, thanks :)

Comment: you'r welcome, happy to hear that you got it fixed :)